# create a random numpy array between -1 and 1 that sum of all element become zero

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to create a NumPy array that all arrays are between -1 to 1. I want to sum all array that becomes zero.
Could you please tell me how can I create this NumPy array?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by creating two arrays with the two values and concatenating them. To finish it all of you shuffle the final concatenated array.

```
import numpy as np
size = 10
array_size = int(size / 2)

ones = np.ones(array_size)
minus_ones = np.full(array_size, -1)

sum_zero = np.concatenate((ones, minus_ones))
np.random.shuffle(sum_zero)
print(sum_zero)
```